# What is the purpose of the scale at the top in TextEdit

Tags: textedit

What is the purpose of the scale at the top of TextEdit.

What are various ways one can make use of that scale?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a Tab ruler, for setting indents, tab stops and other text alignments.

Apple explains it fully here:

[Adjust margins and paragraphs in TextEdit on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/textedit/txte313927e3/mac)

Comment: The downward arrow in the ruler is used to set the right side margin of the text right? but it is only being applied to the new text that I enter but not to the existing text. Is it possible to apply this to existing text as well

Comment: @firstpostcommenter Can't you just select the text and then move the arrow?

Comment: @TomGewecke: ah, that works. Thanks. And what is that downward arrow called(like left tab, center tab, right tab, decimal tab, etc)? Secondly, I changed the whole file to 44 size but still the ruler is displaying till 58, can I change it because I only need till 44 scale